# Is there another way of bash command backgrounding from makefile?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, command-line

I am trying to make a target for a makefile that starts a logger then tails over the file.
The problem is that this logger is blocking, so I would like to send it to the background but if trying to do so the logger crashes because I think is considering the & as an argument.

```
start-logging: DATE_TIME=`date +'%y%m%d_%H%M'`
start-logging: PROJ_ROOT_PATH=../../../..
start-logging: LOGS_PATH=${PROJ_ROOT_PATH}/logs
start-logging: FILE_NAME=${LOGS_PATH}/logger_app_$(DATE_TIME).log
start-logging:
    echo ${FILE_NAME}
    mkdir -p ${LOGS_PATH}
    start_logger_command ${FILE_NAME} &
    sleep 2
    tail -f ${FILE_NAME}
```

Running without the `&` the logger starts and if I stop it the tailing starts.
Also as a side question, how is it possible to freeze the datetime in the filename? so both commands have the same filename?

```
start-logging: DATE_TIME=`date +'%y%m%d_%H%M'`
start-logging: PROJ_ROOT_PATH=../../../..
start-logging: LOGS_PATH=${PROJ_ROOT_PATH}/logs
start-logging: FILE_NAME=${LOGS_PATH}/logger_app_$(DATE_TIME).log
start-logging:
    echo ${FILE_NAME}
    mkdir -p ${LOGS_PATH}
    start_logger_command ${FILE_NAME}
    sleep 2
    tail -f ${FILE_NAME}
```

PS: I can't even do `CTRL+Z` after the logger starts to be able to manually send it to the background. It accepts only `CRTL+C` which stops it.

Comment: A program has no _option_ to treat `&` as an argument -- that's handled by the shell before the command ever starts, so nothing it can do can possibly change it. More likely the program is trying to interact with the TTY in a way that requires being in the foreground.

Comment: ...without knowing how that program is written and what it does, we can't speak to why it insists on TTY interaction. (It's also completely normal for it to not be in the grandparent shell's process table, because it wasn't started by that shell -- it was started by a noninteractive shell that was started by `make`).

Comment: Have you tried : `bash -c "nohup start_logger_command ${FILE_NAME} & exit"` ?

Comment: Thx guys, in fact, I was expecting that ```&``` is removed from the command but I wasn't sure since this weird bug... ```bash -c "nohup start_logger_command ${FILE_NAME} & exit"``` This one has the same effect. From the log I can see that the logger fails to start in the background because of a parameter which is left to the default value that weirdly enough is working ok when running in the foreground.

Comment: Each line of a makefile starts a new sub-shell which is cleaned up before going to the next line.

Comment: "how is it possible to freeze the datetime in the filename?" - `DATE_TIME:=$(shell date +'%y%m%d_%H%M')`.